# AdMob banner overlaps layout content

Tags: android, android-layout, admob

I add my ad programmatically at top of every layout. In LinearLayout everything works fine, but in RelativeLayouts the ad is overlapping the content.

```
// activity
AdHandler.setAd(this, (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_bet), null);

// handler
public class AdHandler {
    private static AdView adView;

    public static void setAd(Context context, RelativeLayout relLayout, LinearLayout linLayout) {
        // Create the adView.
        adView = new AdView(context);
        adView.setAdUnitId(context.getString(R.string.ad_unit_id));
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        // Add the adView to it.
        if (relLayout != null) {
            relLayout.addView(adView, 0);
        }
        else
            linLayout.addView(adView, 0);

        // Initiate a generic request.
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).addTestDevice("034CB02678DF7E469581XXXXX").build();

        // Load the adView with the ad request.
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
}
```

[image]
**EDIT:**

My layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.myfirstapp.LoginActivity" >
    <!-- Loading progress -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/loading_status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/loading_status_message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:text="@string/initial_loading_status_message"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_bet"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_below="@+id/adPlaceholder">

          <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/quoteLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Quote:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/quote"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/quoteLabel"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dateLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Date:"
                android:layout_below="@+id/quote"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/quote"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dateLabel"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/comment"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/dateLabel"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/username"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <ImageView android:id="@+id/verified"
                android:contentDescription="@string/verified"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/username"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_accept"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:visibility="gone" />     

             <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/avatar"
                android:layout_width="64dp"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/username"
                android:contentDescription="Avatar"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/profile"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Go to Profile"
                android:layout_below="@+id/avatar"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/subscribeLoading"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/avatar"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone" />
            </RelativeLayout>        

           <TextView android:id="@+id/bet_listview_header"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:background="#EE2C2C"
                  android:textSize="16sp"
                  android:padding="2dp"
                  android:textStyle="bold"
                  android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                  android:layout_below="@+id/header"
                  android:text="@string/bet_listview_header" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/bet_listview"
                android:layout_below="@+id/bet_listview_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </ListView> 
    </RelativeLayout>
</merge>
```

Comment: You just discovered a major difference between Linear and Relative layout. Post your .xml and I will correct it for you.

Comment: where do u want the Ad Layout will be?

Comment: use admob outsite of layout you are adding text view and everything . and just add android:alignparenttop in admob and android:layout_below="admob" n your relative layout.

Comment: Need your layout.xml file to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/adPlaceholder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlOtherContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/adPlaceholder" >
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The `LinearLayout` "adPlaceholder" will remain empty until you add a Banner to it. If a Banner is added, note the **"layout_below"** property of the `RelativeLayout` representing the main content. It will automatically align itself below the Banner **preventing it from overlapping**.

Code example:

```
LinearLayout placeholder = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.adPlaceholder);
placeholder.addView(AdView);
```

If you want to place the Banner below the `RelativeLayout` of the main content, simply change the order in the .xml file and use the **"layout_above"** property in the `RelativeLayout`, instead of "layout_below".

Comment: I tried to put in above my `activity_bet` layout, but still the same result. I guess it's because of the `<merge>`.

Comment: Basically, you can copy the layout file I posted and put your layout inside my "rlOtherContent". Then use the code I posted above to inflate the ad.